# Programs that can open this AVI file without problems?

Tags: video, audio, avi

I have this AVI file
http://www.sendspace.com/file/mniaz2

Windows Media Player plays it properly.

VLC cuts off in the middle of the last word.

I'm looking for a few other programs-other than WMP- that I can use to play it without cutting off during the last word.

Comment: Have you considered filing this as a bug to the VLC team? I'm sure they're interested in what's causing the issue.

Comment: @Nitrodist I have emailed their mailing list no response yet but they might look into the bug. I am having technical problems accessing their forum so can't post about the problem there.

Comment: so.. i'm looking for a few programs that'll play it

Comment: KM Player is able to play it. So, that and WinAmp

Comment: don't like KM Player, it popped up when I didn't want it and hijacked my icons even after uninstalled, but anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaSource 5 player works fine (as does windows live photo gallery). It is an interesting VLC bug though.

EDIT: Winamp also works.
Edit: Realplayer also works.

Comment: i'm interested in a few plays that do.. but that aside, is MediaSource  available for free anywhere - any link?

Comment: Actually, I'm assuming that it came installed on my system, as I don't recall installing it. here is the link: http://www.creative.com/soundblaster/mediasource/

Comment: @soandos I can't see where to download it there? I meant a download link

Comment: Sorry I did not realize that it did not contain a link to their own product (weird...) here is a link to download: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Other-DRIVERS-TOOLS/Others/Creative-MediaSource-5-Player-Organizer-52023.shtml

Comment: Did the link work?

Comment: @soandos my computer's a bit slow, i'm just installing it.

Comment: no it says it's unable to detect a supported product

Comment: huh. don't know what to tell you then.

Comment: see edit (winamp works)

Comment: +1 that one works.. one program other than WMP  downloadable, that can play it!

Comment: I might accept though it only mentions one. but  this is the best ans far

Comment: Anything else that needs to be found, or just the one is good?

Comment: realplayer also works

Comment: ok great that looks like 3. i've found KM Player.  I don't like realplayer much but realalternative(or I suppose better, quicktime alternative 'cos i think that's meant to be realalternative+ or Media player class + , if I recall), might do it.....